# How to Delete the entire Text when the Part of a Text is highlighted?

Tags: excel, vba

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim strSearch As String
    Dim UserRange As Range
    Dim arySearch As Variant
    Dim searchRng As Range
    Dim cel As Range
    Dim i As Long, ii As Long
    
    Set UserRange = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please Select Range", Title:="Range Select", Type:=8)
    
    strSearch = InputBox("Please Enter Text To Highlight As A Comma Delimited List (Abc, Xyz) it's Case Sensative :", "Highlight Text")
    
    If strSearch = "" Then Exit Sub

    arySearch = Split(strSearch, ",")
    
    For Each cel In UserRange
        With cel
            For ii = LBound(arySearch) To UBound(arySearch)
                i = InStr(cel.Value, arySearch(ii))
                If i > 0 Then
                    .Characters(i, Len(arySearch(ii))).Font.ColorIndex = 3
                End If
            Next ii
        End With
    Next cel
End Sub
```

Example: The sentence is "A tree has apples". If my highlighted word is "apples", I want the entire sentence "A tree has apples" to be deleted.

Help needed on this please.

Comment: Try .Range.Sentences.Item(1).Delete where range is the range of the highlighted word.  But Word doesn't really understand 'Sentences' so be prepared for some unexpected results.

Comment: Thanks for the effort really appreciate it.. But this method is not working for me  unfornately

Comment: Anyone else or if you can make possible edits to the macro it would be much appreciated

Comment: Apologies, thats a word object method, not Excel.

Answer (score 0):

you could try the below which is just a hack.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim strSearch As String
Dim UserRange As Range
Dim arySearch As Variant
Dim searchRng As Range

Set UserRange = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please Select Range", Title:="Range Select", Type:=8)

strSearch = InputBox("Enter Text To Highlight As A Comma Delimited List (Abc, Xyz)", "Highlight Text")

If strSearch = "" Then Exit Sub

arySearch = Split(strSearch, ",")

Dim re As Object    'RegExp
Set re = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")   'New RegExp
re.Global = True
re.IgnoreCase = False
re.MultiLine = True
re.Pattern = "[^.!?\n\r]+[.!?\n\r]*"

Dim cel As Range
For Each cel In UserRange
    Dim cellVal As String, tempVal As String
    cellVal = cel.Value2
    tempVal = cellVal
    
    'get all sentences in the cells Value
    Dim sentences As Object 'MatchCollection
    Set sentences = re.Execute(cellVal)
    
    'loop through each of the user-defined words
    Dim i As Long, ii As Long, cellIndex As Long
    cellIndex = 0
    Dim matchNum As Object  'Match
    For Each matchNum In sentences   'each sentence in the MatchCollection
        For ii = LBound(arySearch) To UBound(arySearch)
            i = InStr(matchNum, arySearch(ii))
            If i > 0 Then
                cel.Characters(cellIndex + i, Len(arySearch(ii))).Font.ColorIndex = 3
                'remove from the temp string
                tempVal = Replace(tempVal, matchNum, "", , , vbBinaryCompare)
            End If
        Next ii
        cellIndex = cellIndex + matchNum.Length
    Next matchNum
    
    'write back value to cell
    cel.Value2 = Trim(tempVal)  ' May wish to trim spaces etc.
Next cel
End Sub
```

Comment: However its taking a lot of time more than 1 hr to delete 10,000 words

Comment: Dim rng As Range

Set rng = [A2:A250]
For Each Cell In rng
 If Cell.Font.ColorIndex = 3 Then
  Cell.ClearContents
 End If
Next Cell

End Sub

Comment: In the above code as well can we do the same method i feel this works faster

Comment: Sorry but I thought there was the possibility of many sentences in a cell. The optimization should be done dependent on your requirements. So let me know if the code solves your problems, accept the answer if so, or else you can show your code, and what the problem is. StackOverflow isn't really supposed to be a code-for-me site. I just gave you some code which it looks like it might help.

Comment: Thanks for you help much appreciated